# sort the contents of a file into a 2 dd list

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

I am trying to sort a file into a two dimensional array. The file looks like this

```
12345 1 893.33
32214 1 343.50
23422 3 903.22
57373 2 893.55
68483 5 329.00
99376 9 329.66
12345 2 999.99
32214 4 892.77
23422 4 895.33
23422 2 492.77
57373 6 985.84
68483 10 1224.90
99376 11 234.56
12345 8 494.44
68483 7 595.55
12345 12 322.22
68483 9 567.85
99376 3 788.77
99376 12 956.66
32214 8 777.77
32214 10 888.88
57373 9 256.56
```

And my current code is this which returns the file exactly as it looks,

```
def print_report(sales_data):
    with open(sales_data) as myfile:
        sales = myfile.read()
    print(sales)  


Enter the name of the sales ids file: salesids.txt
Enter the name of the sales data file: salesdata.txt

 --------Annual Sales Report--------
ID      QT1     QT2     QT3     QT4
12345 1 893.33
32214 1 343.50
23422 3 903.22
57373 2 893.55
68483 5 329.00
99376 9 329.66
12345 2 999.99
32214 4 892.77
23422 4 895.33
23422 2 492.77
57373 6 985.84
68483 10 1224.90
99376 11 234.56
12345 8 494.44
68483 7 595.55
12345 12 322.22
68483 9 567.85
99376 3 788.77
99376 12 956.66
32214 8 777.77
32214 10 888.88
57373 9 256.56
```

I need the list to be sorted so that every ID (12345) with its correct month next to it has the sales all the way on the right and is sorted into the right quarter (QT1 = 1-3  QT2 = 4-6  QT3 = 7-9  QT4 = 10-12

How do I accomplish this?

It should look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Nqz.png)

Comment: Just a suggestion. You can use pandas for this.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. (Unless – rather unlikely – you really want such an image as output.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below in pure Python:

```
def getQuarter(q):
    q = int(q)
    if 1 <= q <= 3:
        return 1
    elif 4 <= q <= 6:
        return 2
    elif 7 <= q <= 9:
        return 3
    else:
        return 4

def printHeaders():
    print("--- Annual sales report ---")
    print("ID\t\t\t",end='')
    print("QT1\t\t\t",end='')
    print("QT2\t\t\t",end='')
    print("QT3\t\t\t",end='')
    print("QT4\t\t\t",end='')
    print("TOTAL\t\t\t")

def printData(currentId, q1, q2, q3, q4, total):
    print(currentId+'\t\t',end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(q1)+'\t\t',end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(q2)+'\t\t',end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(q3)+'\t\t',end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(q4)+'\t\t',end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(total)+'\t\t')

def printFinal(finalQ1, finalQ2, finalQ3, finalQ4, finalTotal):
    print("Total\t\t",end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(finalQ1)+"\t\t",end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(finalQ2)+"\t\t",end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(finalQ3)+"\t\t",end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(finalQ4)+"\t\t",end='')
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(finalTotal)+"\t\t")

def printMaxSalesperson(maxSalesman):
    print("Max sales by salesperson: ID = " + maxSalesman[0] + ", Amount = $" + '{0:.2f}'.format(maxSalesman[1]))

def printMaxQuarterSales(maxQ):
    print("Max sales by quarter: Quarter = " + maxQ[1] + ", Amount = $" + '{0:.2f}'.format(maxQ[0]))

def getListData(inFile):
    data = [elem.split() for elem in sorted([line for line in inFile], key=lambda elem: elem[0])]
    ids = sorted(set([elem[0] for elem in data]))
    newData = [[elem for elem in data if elem[0]==item] for item in ids]
    return newData

def updateSales(sales,elem,q1,q2,q3,q4):
    sales.append([elem[0][0], round(max([q1,q2,q3,q4]),2)])

finalQ1 = finalQ2 = finalQ3 = finalQ4 = finalTotal = 0
sales = []

with open("data.txt", "r") as inFile:
    newData = getListData(inFile)
    printHeaders()
    for elem in newData:
        q1 = q2 = q3 = q4 = total = 0.00
        currentId = elem[0][0]
        for item in elem:
            quarter = getQuarter(item[1])
            if quarter == 1:
                q1 += float(item[2])
            elif quarter == 2:
                q2 += float(item[2])
            elif quarter == 3:
                q3 += float(item[2])
            else:
                q4 += float(item[2])
        updateSales(sales,elem,q1,q2,q3,q4)

        total = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4
        finalQ1 += q1
        finalQ2 += q2
        finalQ3 += q3
        finalQ4 += q4
        finalTotal += total

        printData(currentId, q1, q2, q3, q4, total)
    printFinal(finalQ1, finalQ2, finalQ3, finalQ4, finalTotal)

    maxSalesman = max(sales, key=lambda k: k[1])
    maxQ = max([finalQ1, '1'],[finalQ2, '2'],[finalQ3, '3'],[finalQ4, '4'], key=lambda elem: elem[0])
    printMaxSalesperson(maxSalesman)
    printMaxQuarterSales(maxQ)
```

The output of the above will be:

```
--- Annual sales report ---
ID          QT1         QT2         QT3         QT4         TOTAL           
12345       1893.32     0.00        494.44      322.22      2709.98     
23422       1395.99     895.33      0.00        0.00        2291.32     
32214       343.50      892.77      777.77      888.88      2902.92     
57373       893.55      985.84      256.56      0.00        2135.95     
68483       0.00        329.00      1163.40     1224.90     2717.30     
99376       788.77      0.00        329.66      1191.22     2309.65     
Total       5315.13     3102.94     3021.83     3627.22     15067.12        
Max sales by salesperson: ID = 12345, Amount = $1893.32
Max sales by quarter: Quarter = 1, Amount = $5315.13
```

Feel free to ask any question or if you need any clarification regarding the code.